# Error implementing std::thread with a class method

Tags: c++, stdthread

I have written a simple class, `myshape`, with a class method named `display_area()` that prints area of a rectangle for `N` number of times where `N` will be provided by the user. I want this function to run in a thread independently. However while implementing threading I get error saying

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function  
        std::thread t1(s.display_area, 100);
```

I have seen the related discussion [C++ std::thread and method class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633241/c-stdthread-and-method-class)! where object instances have been created as a pointer unlike my case and could not able to resolve my problem. I am appending my code below for reference. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

class myshape{
  protected:
    double height;
    double width;
  public:
    myshape(double h, double w) {height = h; width = w;}
    void display_area(int num_loop) {
      for (int i = 0; i < num_loop; i++) {
        cout << "Area: " << height*width << endl;
      }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
  myshape s(5, 2);
  s.print_descpirtion();
  std::thread t1(s.display_area, 100);
  t1.join();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, instances are never "created as a pointer". Sometimes instances are dynamically allocated (and this mechanism gives you a pointer to play with by default). But, even when they're not, they still have an address, and you can still get a pointer that represents that address.

The way we use `std::thread`'s constructor has nothing to do with the storage duration of the object whose member function you wish to call.

So, indeed, you should follow those same instructions:

```
std::thread t1(&myshape::display_area, &s, 100);
```

(There's [an example of exactly this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) on cppreference's page for this function.)

As a bonus point of confusion, this constructor *also* allows you to pass a reference instead of a pointer, so the following will also do fine if you're more comfortable with it:

```
std::thread t1(&myshape::display_area, s, 100);
```

Comment: I still get the same error using `std::thread t1(myshape::display_area, s, 100);`

Comment: @Geek I forgot a `&`. Then, after fixing your `print_descpirtion()` _[sic]_ function not existing, [it works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76e9c820cbc28b3c).

Comment: I see that you are compiling with C++17 but I have to compile it using C++11. may be that is reason it does not work for me. For the reference I compile as `g++ -std=c++11 -o test2 test2.cpp`. Any idea?

Comment: @Geek Here's [the same example in C++11 mode](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f4a3d3e0f1fc6d9).

Comment: Ok it now works on my system using `-pthread` option while compiling. So the total compile command should be `g++ -std=c++11 -o test2 test2.cpp -pthread`. However if I use `gcc` instead of `g++` it throws error.

Comment: @Geek Why did you do that?

Comment: I wanted to test if I can compile the same code using `gcc -std=c++11 -o test2 test2.cpp -pthread`.